# How do I preview web pages using the VS Code browser IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-code, web, ide

I am trying to find a way to preview html/css/js page in the VS code web IDE, but all of the relevant extensions are unavailable. Does anybody know of another way I can do this?

I have tried looking for extensions and features built in to the platform with no luck. If there is any way to do this I would love to know.

Comment: what are the "relevant extensions" you are referring to, and why are they unavailable to you?

Comment: I have tried "browser preview" and "live preview" extensions. They are unavailable because I am using the web IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Live Preview extension doesn't support this at the time of this writing, but has an open issue ticket for it: [Make Live Preview work on the web #190](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-livepreview/issues/190). This issue ticket also mentions https://github.com/lostintangent/codeswing, which does have such a feature. Perhaps you could give that a swing <sup><sub>(sorry- I had to make that pun)</sub></sup>.

Comment: Sounds great, thanks! Don't worry, puns are always welcome :)